# Why does Webpack throw error when using this resolve.alias config?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Using an alias key which contains substring of another alias results in an error.

```
//in this given file structure
src
|--app
|   |--module.js
|--component
|   |--module.js
|--config
    |-config.js

//and config
alias: {
     'base': path.resolve('src/config'),
     'base/app': path.resolve('src/app'),
     'base/component': path.resolve('src/component')
}
```

`import app from 'base/config'` 

works as expected, returns module src/config.js

`import app from 'base/app/module'` 

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'base/app/module'

`import app from 'base/component/module'` 

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'base/component/module'

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with how [webpack's enhanced-resolve `AliasPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/blob/master/lib/AliasPlugin.js#L37) works. By having the other `base` be an alias and having other aliases start with `base/`, you're triggering a false positive in this logic that you didn't intend since the path isn't actually below where `base` points to (for `base/app`, `/src/app` is not below `/src/config`)

So, you could either use another delimiter (`_`) for this one instance, or better yet set up aliases that behave how Webpack intends just to avoid breaking changes in the future.

---

So you could replace the `/` with another character, like so:

```
alias: {
     'base': path.resolve('src/config'),
     'base_app': path.resolve('src/app'),
     'base_component': path.resolve('src/component')
}

// ...
import app from 'base_app/module'
```

Or if that's not ideal, you could instead redefine your alias to avoid the issue altogether:

```
alias: {
     'base': path.resolve('src')
}

// ...
import config from 'base/config'
import app from 'base/app/module'
```

Comment: Thanks. I did end up with a solution similar to yours. I am not sure if it could called a bug coz in requirejs world these statements will behave differently.